# What's the difference between -cp and -classpath

Tags: java, command-line

What's the difference between using

`javac -cp classes helloworld.java`

and

`javac -classpath classes helloworld.java`

in CMD?

Comment: One is shorter than the other

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are the same, check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

> -classpath classpath
>   -cp classpath Specifies a list of directories, JAR files, and ZIP archives to search for class files. Separate class path entries with
>   semicolons (;). Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of
>   the CLASSPATH environment variable.
>
> If -classpath and -cp are not used and CLASSPATH is not set, then the
>   user class path consists of the current directory (.).
>
> As a special convenience, a class path element that contains a base
>   name of * is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the
>   files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR. A Java program
>   cannot tell the difference between the two invocations.
>
> For example, if directory mydir contains a.jar and b.JAR, then the
>   class path element mydir/* is expanded to a A.jar:b.JAR, except that
>   the order of jar files is unspecified. All jar files in the specified
>   directory, even hidden ones, are included in the list. A class path
>   entry consisting simply of * expands to a list of all the jar files in
>   the current directory. The CLASSPATH environment variable, where
>   defined, will be similarly expanded. Any class path wildcard expansion
>   occurs before the Java VM is started. No Java program will ever see
>   wild cards that are not expanded except by querying the environment.
>   For example, by calling System.getenv("CLASSPATH").

Answer (score 4):

There's absolutely no difference. It just tells the Java compiler you want to use a custom classpath specified on the command line argument.

So `-cp` and `-classpath` are fully equivalent.

You can find more info on [javac - Java programming language compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) page.

Answer (score 1):

There is none. They're both options for setting the classpath. See the [man page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).